# Using RSA with Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm currently working on a Project where I wanna use RSA for authentification. But as I'm using Java for my Server and C# for my Client I have alot of problems with creating or better initilize the PublicKey class from java.security in Java. I've already used mutlipe solutions for both languages and most of them are working themself.

**So thats my basic C# RSA Client:**

```
public static void NewKeyPair()
    {
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

        //how to get the private key
        var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
        //and the public key ...
        var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

        _ = privKey.Modulus;
        _ = pubKey.Modulus;
    }

    public void Encrypt(string text, string publicKey)
    {
        RSAParameters para = new RSAParameters();
        para.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);

        //conversion for the private key is no black magic either ... omitted

        //we have a public key ... let's get a new csp and load that key
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(para);


        //for encryption, always handle bytes...
        var bytesPlainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        //apply pkcs#1.5 padding and encrypt our data 
        var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);

        //we might want a string representation of our cypher text... base64 will do
        var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);

    }


    public static void Decrypt(string encryptedText, RSAParameters para)
    {

        var bytesCypherText = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

        //we want to decrypt, therefore we need a csp and load our private key
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(para);

        //decrypt and strip pkcs#1.5 padding
        var bytesPlainTextData = csp.Decrypt(bytesCypherText, false);

        //get our original plainText back...
        var plainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytesPlainTextData);
    }
```

So this is basically from a Microsoft doc if I remmeber right.

**Meanwhile that's my Java code:**

```
    public static KeyPair gen() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(1024);
    return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
}

public static String encrypt(String message, PublicKey pk) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, PrivateKey pk) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText)));
}
```

So for connecting those I'm exporting the Key first in C# with

```
Convert.ToBase64String(csp.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()
```

After writing this to Console I paste it into this code snip in Java:

```
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(""));
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    
// Encrypting
String encrypted = encrypt("Hello", pubKey);
```

Afterwards I'm checking everythink by decrypting it again in C# ( Mostly failing before at `keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);` )

Also though aleady that's maybe caused by the byte system as c# using unsigned and java signed, but don't really have an idea how to fix that.
Someone has an idea how to solve this problem? c:

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just to be for sure - you generate the RSA keypair in C#, export the public key in C#, transport the public key to the server, rebuild the public key there and encrypt some data. Then the encrypted data is transported to the client where it will be decrypted with the private key present on C#-side? Why do you generate a RSA keypair on server/java-side as well ?

Comment: Yeah as you said @MichaelFehr. The client sends Public Key -> Server encrypt sth, -> Client decrypt it with Private Key. And I'm not using the keypair generator on server for this situation. It's for the other direction as I planed to have 2 directions, so Client can send a public key to the Server and the server can give the client also an public key if it 's requested.

Comment: Theoretical it's easy - a private and public key are "just" a modulus and an exponent. When generating the key pair in C# just get an XML-file when exporting, on Java side simply get both data, transform them into BigInteger variables and rebuild the public key with the data. For the other way round (seen from Server/Java side) generate the key pair, cast the public key to a RSAPublicKey, get modulus and exponent and "built" the xml-file from this data -> use this on C#-side to the RSA routine to encrypt data. In the end it's some work with xml and base64 encoding.

Comment: One reason for cross-platform-failure is the different encoding (conversions) of string to byte[] and vice versa. On C# you are using Unicode encoding while on Java side (per default) UTF8-encoding takes place [as you did not specify the encoding while converting on my machine UTF8 is chosen]. For further testing I recommend the usage of fixed key pairs and to convert the public key from xml-format/-encoding to a pem-format/_encoding via an online service.